# Android Studio 2.2.3 Base.Theme.AppCompat Error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

[Android Studio Version 2.2.3 - Click here to see the Screen Shot of my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3CxL.png)

I am currently working on a school project. My issue is getting past this error when I attempt to add the new theme name to the XML code in the styles.xml file. The project is wanting me to use Base.Theme.AppCompat. When I do so I get errors. Please help! Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to SO, it really helps if you 1) include the code you are having issues with and 2) include any errors.

Comment: Absolutely. I attached a screen shot within the title of my question. Can you view that? In the mean time I will work on getting it posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project seems to have a dependency with 'Appcompat' library. Please add this library to project.

If you use API 25, you may add this library in gradle file as following.

```
dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
       ...
}
```

Comment: Well this fixed it. I was using API 25. It had to rebuild the Gradle afterwords then I was able to retype the "Base.Theme.AppCompat" within my styles.xml file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your activity change

public class ActivityName extends AppCompatActivity
to
public class ActivityName extends Activity

then you will be able to use any Theme